# How to update a array in cloud firestore js

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Cloud Firestore by Google and I can't update a array ...
So, if someone have a solution.

```
docRef.get()
    .then(function(doc) { 
        if ( doc.exists ) { db.collection("collection")
        .doc("document").update({ "array"[0]: true }) 
    .then(function() { 
              console.log("Changed !"); 
    }) 
} })
```

Comment: please add your code how you update an array at Firestore?

Comment: docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                        db.collection("collection").doc("document").update({
                            "array"[0]: true
                        })  
                        .then(function() {
                            console.log("Changed !");
                        }) 
                }
            })

Comment: Console log say : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: @Taupeman You are able to edit your question to add further details.

Comment: Seams `{ "array"[0]: true }` is wrong format. Instead replace a valid array something like : `newArr`, and previously define and `newArr` array that you wanted to replace. Something like : `.update({array: newArr }) `

Comment: Ok , it works. Thanks